# CSSでwidthに設定した値がchromeのデベロッパーツールをみると小数点のつく微妙にずれた数字になっている。

Tags: css

CSSで`width`に設定した値がchromeのデベロッパーツールをみると小数点のつく微妙にずれた数字になっています。

`width:740`としているのに、デベロッパーツール上では、**739.589**のような半端な数値になってしまっています。

また、`padding;20`と設定すると、**19.5**となっていたりします。
`padding:30`と設定すると30となるのですが。

何故なのでしょうか？

Comment: とりあえず適当な div タグに `width: 740px` を指定してみましたが、再現しませんでした(https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfPn6.png)。サンプルコードを提示していただけないでしょうか？あるいは確認方法が違うのであれば、それがわかる画面キャプチャなどを載せてもらえるとわかりやすいです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

chromeの表示が100%表示になっていなかったのが原因のようです！
縮小して‌​いくと一定のところで端数になります。